# Agregar elementos Dictionary C#

Tags: c#

estoy estudiando C# y tengo una duda, en un tutorial que estoy siguiendo se hace lo siguiente

```
if (record.HasRows){
Dictionary<string, string> row;
while (record.Read()){
row = new Dictionary<string, string>();
for (int f = 0; f < record.FieldCount, f++){
row.Add(record.GetName(f), record.Getvalue(f);
    }
  }
}
```

Mi duda es que no comprendo por que se instancio row dentro del ciclo While, esto no haria que se cree repetidamente mientras record sigue leyendose?
y a lo que tengo entendido solo se necesita instanciar una sola vez para poder agregar N elementos, no cada vez  que se quiera agregar algo. No deberia haberse instanciado en el condicional if en vez de dentro del While?

Answer (score 0):

Si, así es, no debería instanciar de nuevo `row`en cada iteración. Se debería instanciar una sola vez e ir agregando sus elementos en cada iteración.

```
if (record.HasRows){
    Dictionary<string, string> row = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    while (record.Read()){
        for (int f = 0; f < record.FieldCount, f++){
            row.[record.GetName(f)]  =  record.Getvalue(f);
        }
    }
}
```

Por su parte, recomendable validar bien el `Add`ya que si  la llave ya existe en el diccionario te va a dar error (Por eso utilicé el `=`)

Answer (score 0):

Ese codigo no es correcto

- primero no necesitas preguntar por el `HasRows` ya que el while no ingresara sino puede posicionar el cursor
- si defines el diccionario dentro del if el ambito sera solo ese, con lo cual no podras usarlo por fuera

Ademas esta raro los datos que quieres volcar porque es una matriz o tabla y no se puede aplanar de esa forma, necesitas una estructura que refleje filas y columnas

seria algo como esto

```
var Items = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

while (record.Read())
{
    var row = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    for (int f = 0; f < record.FieldCount, f++)
    {
        row.Add(record.GetName(f), record.Getvalue(f));
    }

    Items.Add(row);
}
```

La lista seria cada registro y la composicion de la row serian las columnas representada en el diccionario